# Content switching Vs VIP

Tags: netscaler

I am new to netscaler and trying to understand it.
I have a VIP configured on netscaler.
I want to understand that if I have a VIP on netscaler, how can I find cs vServer corresponding to this VIP.
Is VIP same as cs vServer?

Answer (score 0):

For version 11.0:

To find if the VIP corresponds to Content Switching vserver, expand the Traffic Management section in the web management interface. Then expand Content Switching and select Virtual Servers. Here you will see the list of all CS vservers. In the IP address column, you will see the IPs associated with the CS vserver.

[Snapshot of web managment interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obne6.png)

Alternatively, from command line you can do

```
show cs vserver
```

Answer (score 0):

You could ssh to login and execute following cmd "show run | grep [your VIP address>]".

Then you will find what's your VIP related to CSVserver or LBVserver or something else.